# 413 Request Entity Too Large In Joomla 3.3

Tags: php, apache, joomla, joomla3.3

Hello all i'm getting this error when I'm posting new articles of 4500 lines it says

> Request Entity Too Large
>
> The requested resource /administrator/index.php does not allow request
>   data with **GET** requests, or the amount of data provided in the
>   request exceeds the capacity limit. Additionally, a 404 Not Found
>   error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle
>   the request.

I did change in php.ini with but still same error

```
   max_input_time = 24000
   max_execution_time = 24000
   upload_max_filesize = 12000M
   post_max_size = 30000M
   memory_limit = 12000M
```

it runs on Joomla! 3.3.6 Stable [ Ember ]

Comment: Check the actual php error_log if possible, to see what limit you're actually hitting

Comment: It might also be the apache server setting `LimitRequestBody` if you're serving this with apache

Answer (score 3):

Set following line in nginx configuration file (nginx.conf) if your joomla portal is on nginx server:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Restart nginx and now plugin installation will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @Kevin noted this is a configuration issue with your web server. If you're using Apache the configuration you want to modify is `LimitRequestBody`.

If using nginx the directive is `client_max_body_size`